# how to make Ad View not interfere with my Page controls?

Tags: windows-phone-7, admob

while my phone acquires a wifi network for loading ads(Google Admob), the controls(image) of my page gets unresponsive.

i am not doing anything apart from using this code in my .xaml?

```
        <google:BannerAd AdUnitID="MyAdUnitId" Name="AdControl">
            <google:BannerAd.TestDeviceIDs>
                <sys:String>MyId</sys:String>
            </google:BannerAd.TestDeviceIDs>
        </google:BannerAd>
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
Google admob for Windows Phone is buggy and it seems they don't care.
I stop using it in favor of other better implemented ad network controls.
Don't bother trying to post on AdMob forums, they auto-delete any post containing the words admob and windows phone.